# Rails with AJAX trimming contents of field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, json

I have a model called Content with two fields 'before' and 'after'.

Before creating the record, I do some preprocessing on field 'before' and store it in 'after'. No problem here.

Problem is when I load the show page the contents in 'before' display incomplete. I'm trimming white spaces after a period if there are 2 or more... 
e.g.

```
"this is.   some text.   with many spaces.   after the periods."
```

The view shows me that 'before' looks like this:

```
"this is. some text. with many spaces. after the periods."
```

If I look at the .json version the 'before' field contains the original format - why then does the rails view (non-json) present the 'before' as being "trimmed"?

This is my _content.html.erb

```
<li><%= content.before %></li>
<li><%= content.after %></li>
```

This is my show.js.erb

```
$("#main").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @content) %>");
```

This is the show definition in contents_controller.rb

```
  respond_to :html, :json

  def show
    @content = Content.find(params[:id])
    respond_with(@content)
  end
```

This is the pre-processing in my model content.rb

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base

    before_validation :format_params

    def format_params
        rm_spaces = /\.\s{2,}/              # regex to rm extra spaces
        new_format = '. '                   # only one space after period
        self.after = before.gsub(rm_spaces, new_format)
    end
end
```

And here are some screenshots of what I mean.

[image: the view]

[image: the json]

**Edit**
I believe this is the code that is getting executed since I tried Swards recommendation and it did not work.

This is the code for my highlighting function in my contents_helper.rb

```
def highlight_changes(text)
    highlighter = '<span style= "background: yellow">\1</span>'
    matcher = /(\.\s{2,})/
    text.gsub(matcher, highlighter).html_safe
end
```

This is the code in show.html.rb

```
<p>
  <strong>Before:</strong>
  <!-- call the helper method to highlight changes made -->
  <%= highlight_changes @content.before %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a `.before` class on the before li and add this to css to see it as it was entered.

```
<li class="before"><%= content.before %></li>
<li><%= content.after %></li>
```

in the css

```
.before {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: What class did you put on the li?

Comment: I tried  `<li class="before>` but that didn't work, and I also tried inserting the class directly into the helper function that I am using for highlighting. Will edit post to show this code

Comment: Just curious - try a pre instead of a p tag around the content in show.html

Comment: Nice! pre tag in show.html was exactly what I needed. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the browser that omits extra spaces. You can use `&nbsp;` to make a whitespace instead.

To transform your string you could try

```
content.before.gsub(' ', '&nbsp;').html_safe
```

This replaces each space with `&nbsp;` and then tells rails not to escape the html characters (`&nbsp;`).

Warning:If the `before` field is input by users then using `html_safe` is dangerous as it could allow users to inject malicious code.